# I am trying to call an ajax method but this calls error function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to call a request through ajax but its not working  it does not go to success function . it goes to error function . please help to figure out i cant figure what's the problem .

Here is my ajax method which is called on save button click

```
function save(){
    let lang = document.getElementById("valueoflang").value;
   let audio= document.getElementById("valueoffile").value;
  

    $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'get',
            url: 'admin/test-lesson/saveaudio',
            data:{
                lang :lang,
                id:133,
                file:audio,
                
            },
          
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function(data){
                console.log("error");
                  }
            
            });
}
```

In console **error** is coming. i checked in network tab request status 200.                      Here is the my method where to request gone

```
 public function saveAudio(Request $request)
    {
       dd($request->get("lang"));
       if($request->ajax()){
        return "AJAX";
        }
    
    return response()->json([
            
        'output'=>"Not working",
    ], 400);
    }
```

Here is my route

```
Route::get('admin/test-lesson/saveaudio', 'TextLessonsController@saveAudio');
```

Ajax request is not gone to **saveAudio** method. I dont know why?

Comment: yes. I also post my route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you defined the route?

```
Route::get('admin/test-lesson/saveaudio', 'YourControllerName@saveAudio')->name('save.audio');
```

Then add the route name in ajax url property:

```
function save() {
    let lang = document.getElementById("valueoflang").value;
    let audio = document.getElementById("valueoffile").value;

    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'get',
        url: "{{ route('save.audio') }}",
        data: {
            lang: lang,
            id: 133,
            file: audio,
        },

        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: "Then add the route name in ajax url property" its working . thanks for help

Comment: Well if it doesn't work:  In your main Blade file define the base URL like: var baseUrl = "{{ url('/') }}"; and then -    url: baseUrl + "/admin/test-lesson/saveaudio",